# How to compute the number of solutions of primitive modulo equation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the equation: 
$$x^p \equiv a \pmod{M}$$
where $p, a$ and $M$ is given. Is there a quick way to compute the number of solutions to the above equation?
I'm so rusty in Number Theory now, so any paper or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The general answer is  complicated. Things are relatively simple if $M$ is an odd prime.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Interesting, unfortunately $M \in [1, 40]$, but thanks anyway.

Comment: When $\mathbb{Z}^\times_M$ is cyclic, using a primitive makes this question straightforward. Otherwise, we can decompose $M$ to its factors, solve for each of those, and use the Chinese reminder theorem.

Comment: For such tiny numbers, one can give a complete description.